# List won't add string Array

Tags: c#

I created the following class:

```
class TrdRamValue
    {
        double Value = 0.0;
        TrdState State = TrdState.Ok;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
```

I then created a list with this class to store the information:

```
List<TrdRamValue> DMSrows = new List<TrdRamValue> ();
```

And I use the following inside a Handler to constantly insert values every second:

```
string[] value = new string[3];
value[0] = val;
value[1] = val.Error.ToString ();
value[2] = val.Time.ToString ();
DMSrows.AddRange (value);
```

But in code it keeps saying that I have an error in my argument, that I can't convert string[] to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.

I'm completely lost on this one...

**ANSWER:**
It was just a minor error from my part, and I also took huMpty duMpty suggestion since he's completely right, I don't need that string array.

All I had to do was make the class and the variables inside public in order to do what huMpty duMpty told me.

```
public class TrdRamValue
    {
        public double Value = 0.0;
        public TrdState State = TrdState.Ok;
        public DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
```

Then apply huMpty duMpty suggestion:

```
TrdRamValue value = new TrdRamValue() ;
value.Value = val;
if (!val.Error) {
    value.State = TrdState.Ok;
}
else if (val.Error) value.State = TrdState.Error;
value.dt = val.Time;
DMSrows.Add (value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need string array here.

Also you don't need [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) here since you adding one item. You can use [List.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx)

```
   DMSrows.Add(new TrdRamValue{
           Value =val,
           State =val.Error,
           dt =val.Time
     });
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, it was just a minor error from my part, sorry about that.
I also updated my question and added your answer.
Dunno why all those downvotes though.

Comment: @StevenBorges: downvotes are probably because of the error you did in the code! Seems you didn't explain the question properly in the first place :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `List` is not a `List<string>` but a `List<TrdRamValue>`. Therefore, you cannot add strings to the list. You can only add instances of `TrdRamValue`, or, in the case of AddRange, an `IEnumerable` (such as an array) of `TrdRamValue`.

So you can do this:

```
TrdRamValue toAdd = new TrdRamValue { Value = val, State = ..., dt = ... };
dmsRows.Add(toAdd);
```

(btw naming a variable `DMSRows` does not fit with the .net naming conventions).

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to add strings to a list of `TrdRamValue` objects. Your list is type-safe, which means you are only allowed to add `TrdRamValue` objects to it.